# android listview with custom cursor adapter and multiple views- bindView only specific view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a small problem with my listview. the list has 3 different views:

1 for the first list cell

1 for the second list cell

1 for all the rest list cells.

all the "rest" lists cells are populated using data from sqlite. 
problem is that in the first 2 binds the cursor advances 2 times.

I know that i can rewind the cursor using cursor.moveToX methods but that involves counters
and syncing those counters each time the list is repopulated (which can be dangerous and buggy)

Is there a more elegant solution from my problem: bindView only to 1 view from the 3 i have?

Thanks!

Roy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first two rows are static and don't actually need to be configured by the list adapter, you can use [`ListView.addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) to add rows above the ones that your adapter builds. You must call this **before** you call `setAdapter` on the ListView.

Note that in any `onItemClickListener` you will need to offset the reported clicked position by the number of header views to find the correct item in your adapter's data set.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. the first 2 items are indeed static but clickable. there is no problem with that right?

Comment: No problem at all. I only mentioned that last part in the event you want to look up items in your data set based on the position that gets reported to the `onItemClickListener`, since that same listener will be called if the header views are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the adapters have **`setViewBinder`** which can be used to custom bind the values to view.

Return false in `setViewValue` for the adapter to bind, and for the rest of the cases you should custom bind the values and return true

Comment: thanks for your quick response (-:. i'm extending CursorAdapter and there are no setViewBinder method

Comment: can you extend simplecursorAdapter, that has the method